# Facebook triangle arrow

Tags: html, css, facebook

[image]

Any idea how Facebook does this? I'm trying to use it on backgrounds that aren't solid so trying to cover parts of the image using the CSS Triangles aren't going to work. I figured I could try using border-image but I'm not getting anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try a CSS mask?

Comment: @z0mbieparade looks like CSS mask is indeed what I'm looking for. Caniuse says it's not supported on FF though but I'm seeing it on Facebook using FF. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FSwx2/) solution ;)

**UPDATE for firefox**:
http://jsfiddle.net/FSwx2/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-image">
            <div class="image-properties">
                <img class="image-fix" src="http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/xp/finepix_xp100/features/img/index/pic_02.jpg"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle-image">
        <div class="deg-fix">
            <img class="image-fix" src="http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/xp/finepix_xp100/features/img/index/pic_02.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 137px;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    width: 370px;
}
.main-image {
    height: 137px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.image-properties {
    height: 159px;
    position: relative;
    top: -11px;
    width: 370px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-image {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(24px, -12px) rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.deg-fix {
    width: 370px; 
    height: 159px; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-24px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    top:0;
}
.image-fix {
    left:-31px; 
    top:0px;
    width:432px;
    height:160px;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. I'm on FF right now so I'm not seeing it but this is clever. Thanks a lot!

Comment: try add moz prefixes or removo webkit prefix

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this effect using `:after` or `:before` pseudo selector. Here is a **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ruviguma/1/)**. and ***[updated Demo](http://jsbin.com/ruviguma/4/)***

```
div{
width:200px;
height:100px; 
background:gray;
position:relative;
top:20px;
}

div:after
{
content: ""; 
position:absolute;
top:-15px; 
left:0; 
width:0px;
height:0px;
border-left: 15px solid transparent;
border-right: 15px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 15px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I was trying a triangle with the image in it as shown in the question. Like a part of the whole image is cut off but a triangle stays.

Comment: No I mean a part of the image is IN the triangle.